# Getting large images from mulesoft into salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

So currently I am doing a synchronous call to mulesoft which returns raw image(no encoding is done) and then storing the image in a document.So when ever we are getting bigger images more than 6 MB it is hitting the governerlimit for max size.So wanted to know is there a way to get a reduced or compressed image

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if Mule has anything to preprocess images, compress...

In apex you could try to make the operation asynchronous to benefit from 22 mb limit. But there wil be no UI element for it anymore, your component / user would have to periodically check if the file got saved or something.

you could always change the direction. Make Mule push to salesforce over standard API instead of apex code pulling from Mule. From what I remember standard files API is good for up to 2GB.
Maybe send some notification to mule that you want file XYZ attached to account 123, mule would insert contentversion, contentdocumentlink? And have apex periodically check.
And when file is not needed - nightly job to delete files created by "Mr mule" over a week ago?